# how to get a parameter's name from a json object in javascript ?

Tags: javascript, json

i would like to get the parameter name of a json object as a string

```
myObject = { "the name": "the value", "the other name": "the other value" }
```

is there a way to get `"the name"` or `"the other name"` as a result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery:

```
var myObject = { "the name": "the value", "the other name": "the other value" };
var indexes = [];
$.each(myObject,function(index,value){
   indexes.push(index);
});

console.log(indexes[0]) -> the name
console.log(indexes[1]) -> the other name
```

In pure js:

```
var myObject = { "the name": "the value", "the other name": "the other value" };
var indexes = [];
for(var index in myObject){
    indexes.push(index);
}

console.log(indexes[0]) -> the name
console.log(indexes[1]) -> the other name
```

In above you could break whenever you would like. If you need all the indexes, there is faster way to put them in array:

```
var myObject = { "the name": "the value", "the other name": "the other value" };
var indexes = Object.keys(myObject);

console.log(indexes[0]) -> the name
console.log(indexes[1]) -> the other name
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You can use a `for-in` loop to get property names of the object.

```
for ( var prop in myObject ){
   console.log("Property name is: " + prop + " and value is " + myObject[prop]);
}
```

[More info on for-in here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what you want to accomplish, but you can get the keys to the object pretty easily with 
Object.keys(object)

```
Object.keys(myObject)
```

That will give you an array of the object's keys, which you could do whatever you want with.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers will let you use the `Object.keys` method to get a list of keys (that's what the strings you are looking for are called) from a JSON object. So, you can simply use

```
var keys = Object.keys(myJsonObject);
```

to get an array of the keys and do with these as you wish.